# Saving new associated records in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations, save

So I have a `Message` model. When a message is created, I want to create new `Recipient` records. (Message hasMany Recipient, Recipient belongsTo Message).

The intent is that the `message_id` field in these associated records gets populated automagically with the new `Message` id.

I've tried to format the data every which way, and am aware of `saveAll` and `saveAssociated` methods, but nothing seems to work... Here's what I assumed would work:

Data passed on to save:

```
[Message] => array
    (
        [subject] => Foo bar
        [body] => Blah blah blah.
    )
[Recipient] => array
    (
        [0] => array
            (
                [user_id] => 1
            )
        [1] => array
            (
                [user_id] => 5
            )
        [2] => array
            (
                [user_id] => 6
            )
    )
```

Using saveMany, saveAll, saveAssociated didn't seem to make a difference (even with 'deep' set to true).

Comment: are there validation rules on Recipient?

Comment: Nope! Nothing. I'm able to save fine when I manually save... I'd just rather keep my code lean and conventional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1) The Message being created was a new record. I realized after that I didn't have `$this->Message->create()` in my controller. Now, I've since tried without and it works fine but I believe it's best practice to include it.

2) Since I need to save multiple associated records, I have to use `saveAll` or `saveMany` but doing so was causing extra blank rows to be added, since the main record was not numerically indexed (which is what `saveAll` wants).

So here's some code from my controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Message->create();
    if ($this->Message->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true))) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

And here is how my data is structured:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Message] => Array
                (
                    [subject] => Foo
                    [body] => bar
                    [Recipient] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [user_id] => 1
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [user_id] => 6
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [user_id] => 38
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

)
```

This will create a new `Message` and properly associate the newly created `Recipient` records.